# In a Blockchain.com wallet, Should I need to add the fees amount in the sent Bitcoin amount?

Tags: blockchain.info

I need to send an exact amount from my Blockchain.com wallet, will the fee be taken the amount straight out of the amount being sent or do I need to add the fee to the amount being sent?

Example: Let's say the blockchain requests exactly 0.00075 bitcoins(30$), fee is 0.000055(2.20$). Do I send 0.0008 bitcoins(32.20$) or do I send 0.00075 and it takes the fee from main balance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the wallet to look like the below image when you choose "send"

[image: wallet screenshot]

You set the fee separately by clicking the **▼** drop-down fee selector in the "Fee" section near the bottom of the screen just above the "Continue" button. So the amount you enter in the "BTC" section is the amount for the recipient *excluding the transaction fee*.

If your wallet looks different, you could contact customer support provided by the business that provides your wallet.